# Is "Termination with Gross Misconduct" possible after 3 months from finding that out?

Tags: human-resources, termination, legal, mistakes, ireland

My friend Bob was using the company's computer to download movies. He got caught 3 months ago, taken under disciplinary procedure and asked "Are you downloading files by using p2p software?" Bob denied it, although he knows he got caught because they mentioned the name of the software specifically.

Now, 3 months later, things between Bob and the management got ugly. And the HR called for another disciplinary procedure, and said "We recently(!) found out that you were using p2p programs at work. And we decided to fire you because of Gross Misconduct."

Are the companies allowed to hold the evidence for rainy days just like in this example? Are there any day limitations for them to use it after they find out?

Note: It's an EU country.

Comment: I'm guessing that the HR process being used here is company or industry specific.  I'm not sure this question is answerable here.

Comment: VTC  This is a legal and/or policy issue which we are not suited to address

Comment: The hint here is, the first thing he (HR manager) said was "I am not familiar with the technical stuff but these files has been recently recovered from your folders". Giving this complete irrelevant information gives him away.

Comment: Given Bob's original denial, the employer might have taken the time to get an expert to examine the evidence. Do you think they should have fired Bob immediately, despite his denial, without doing that?

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan Thats good and logical answer, but lets say for the story's sake Bob knows that that's not the case and there is nothing to examine.

Comment: @StukaPilot If that were the case, Bob's lie was not only unethical but stupid, and he should be fired any time management feels that the hassle of keeping him is greater than the hassle of firing him.

Comment: This question is not asking for legal advice it asking about standard policies and procedures that our experts should be able to help with.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: Questions that ask "are companies allowed..." are unambiguously legal questions.

Answer (score 3):

Typically there is a section in the employee handbook that **discusses the use of company resources for personal use**.  Furthermore, the company typically requires you to sign an acknowledgement of understanding regarding the contents of the employee handbook.

If this is indeed the cases, **then yes the company can let Bob go**.  I am not certain if there is a number of days limitation -- that may be more of a legal question.

Also something to consider, the company may have been doing its due diligence to see if they were in their rights to remove Bob -- explaining any delay.

Comment: Without knowing the specifics, I'd guess that the HR department were following the process.  "Bob" got a warning for the first problem and placed on probation.  Things didn't improve, so termination is the next logical step.

Comment: Thanks @Mister Positive, they definitely have the right to do that. The unknown fact, is until when? I am completely sure that they dont wait 3 months to research the status.

Comment: You would be surprised.  In the USA at least, these events are very situational.  I have seen it take over a year for an HR \ Management team to act on a termination.  I have also seen it happen immediately.

Comment: I would at least enquire about this legally. A very short google has links that say there is a limit of 1 month for an employer to fire someone for gross misconduct, although the offence can be taken into account in addition to another breach(this is from a UK legal website). Nobody here is a lawyer but if I was Bob I would at least investigate if I have legal recourse.

Comment: I have seen people fired and escorted off site _immediately_ when they did something this stupid. Your friend has no excuse and probably no recourse -- he was involving the company in copyright theft, and he's lucky not to get sued for the potential damage to the company's reputation.

Comment: @Dustybin80, are we suggesting Bob should sue because they didn't fire him fast enough?  Sounds more like they did due diligence and gave him a limited second chance.  He's lucky he got paid for three months when he should have been looking for a job.

Comment: @cdkMoose I am not suggesting he should sue at all. I merely suggested he investigate if they behaved legally. If they must act within X amount of time and they didn't he could have a case. How do we know he is lucky he got paid for three months? They might have wanted him to finish a critical piece of work and dragged this up to avoid paying him redundancy.

Comment: @Dustybin80 3 months is nothing - if the delay was a year or more, then you might have something to go to a tribunal with, but 3 months can easily be chalked down to administrative processes and due diligence.

Comment: @Moo do you know employment that is the law of the Republic of Ireland or the full facts? It might come to nothing but nobody here is qualified to decide that '3 months is nothing' and that procedures were followed correctly. He can contact citizens information for free advice so this doesn't need to an expensive exercise. The original post taken at face value states that Bob received a disciplinary for an offence and then three months later was punished again for the same offence. There is nothing to suggest in the post that bob was under investigation for three months that is speculation.

Comment: @Dustybin80 in any jurisdiction it would be *extremely* hard in a tribunal to argue against further action taken in such a short time, especially if the relationship between the employee and employer deteriorated.  As I said, 3 months is nothing - is the same as many companies probationary period - the decision and due process needed to fire him may have taken that period of time.  So yes, 3 months can indeed be "recently" in the context of the question, and it doesnt mean he is being punished twice, it just means the ultimate punishment took time to arrive at.

Comment: @Dustybin80 there are a multitude of issues here, and as you say we dont know all the facts, but there is nothing here to suggest that the company is in the wrong with its timescales, in any EU country.

Comment: @Moo I think you're making an assumption that this was part of an ongoing investigation and without that being confirmed the debate about time scale for investigation is moot. Since we don't know if Bob was put on a disciplinary path or punished in the first instance we can't even speculate if three months is a reasonable period. There are laws that address double punishment for the same offence so I stand by that Bob actually gets some proper advice if he feels aggrieved with his version.

Comment: @Dustybin80 I think you are making an assumption that Bob can realistically argue it wasn't an ongoing investigation.  All we know from the question is that the company discovered something, Bob lied about it by denying all knowledge and 3 months later the discovery was used to terminate him.  There are so many multiple ways to spin that in favour of the company that Bob has basically no legal recourse here at all - all the company has to do is say "after investigation, we determined the employee lied during the original disciplinary process and that added subsequent grounds for termination".

Comment: @Moo I don't believe I am making any assumption. I am making a suggestion that he takes the facts as he sees them to somebody with the knowledge and experience to judge if this is worth pursing. I am not in possession of the facts let alone a trained lawyer. You've made the assumptions that A) They have followed their own disciplinary procedure correctly B) They have cast iron proof that Bob used the software C) That their procedures are even legal to start with. You then appear to be using those assumptions to advise him to drop it.